# How can i change the default list style of an unordered list to an image and get the output like so

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, html5-canvas

[i am trying to get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBJym.png)
i tried to replicate this but the check marks became small sized (the image being used was an svg file) like so in the below picture.
[i am stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjIF.png)
The CSS code i used:

```
li{
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  list-style-image: url("images/download.svg");
}
```

And i also don't know on how to add the background color to replicate the process.can you show me on how to get the output as in the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
ul {

  list-style-type: none;

}


ul li:before {

  content: '';

  display: inline-block;

  height: 10px;

  width: 10px;

   background-size: 10px;

  background-image: url("http://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/star/1-red-star-png-image-thumb.png");

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  margin-right: 5px;

}
```

Comment: Thnx for investng your valueable time sir; i used your code but how can i increase the size of the red-star being displayed there and also change the background color and radius as i have shown on the example pic above